# Undefined symbol when importing tf-sentencepiece

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, pip

On my MacBook (version 10.14.6) I am succesfully running a Django application including TensorFlow and tf-sentencepiece (in particular to use the universal sentence encoder model). When I perform a `pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt` I get the following required packages:

```
-i https://pypi.org/simple
absl-py==0.8.1
aniso8601==7.0.0
astor==0.8.0
bert-embedding==1.0.1
boto3==1.10.34
boto==2.49.0
botocore==1.13.34
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
coreapi==2.3.3
coreschema==0.0.4
cycler==0.10.0
defusedxml==0.6.0
diff-match-patch==20181111
django-cors-headers==3.2.0
django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf==0.18
django-elasticsearch-dsl==0.5.1
django-filter==2.2.0
django-import-export==2.0
django-neomodel==0.0.4
django-nine==0.2.2
django-pandas==0.6.1
django-rest-framework==0.1.0
django-rest-swagger==2.2.0
django==2.2.8
djangorestframework==3.10.3
docutils==0.15.2
elasticsearch-dsl==6.1.0
elasticsearch==6.4.0
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
gast==0.3.2
gensim==3.8.1
gluonnlp==0.6.0
graphene-neo4j==2.2.3.9
graphene==2.1.8
graphql-core==2.2.1
graphql-relay==2.0.1
graphviz==0.8.4
grpcio==1.25.0
h5py==2.10.0
idna==2.8
ipaddress==1.0.23
itypes==1.1.0
jdcal==1.4.1
jinja2==2.10.3
jmespath==0.9.4
joblib==0.14.0
keras-applications==1.0.8
keras-preprocessing==1.1.0
kiwisolver==1.1.0
lazy-import==0.2.2
lxml==4.4.2
markdown==3.1.1
markuppy==1.14
markupsafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.1.2
mock==3.0.5
mxnet==1.4.0
neo4j-driver==1.6.3
neomodel-next==3.5.2.5
neomodel==3.3.1
neotime==1.7.4
nltk==3.4.5
numpy==1.14.6
odfpy==1.4.0
openapi-codec==1.3.2
openpyxl==3.0.2
pandas==0.25.3
promise==2.2.1
protobuf==3.11.1
pycld2==0.41
pyparsing==2.4.5
python-dateutil==2.8.0
pytorch-pretrained-bert==0.6.2
pytz==2019.3
pyyaml==5.2
regex==2019.11.1
requests==2.22.0
risparser==0.4.3
rx==1.6.1
s3transfer==0.2.1
scikit-learn==0.22
scipy==1.3.3
simplejson==3.17.0
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.13.0
sklearn==0.0
smart-open==1.9.0
sqlalchemy==1.3.11
sqlparse==0.3.0
tablib==0.14.0
tensorboard==1.13.1
tensorflow-estimator==1.13.0
tensorflow-hub==0.7.0
tensorflow==1.13.1
termcolor==1.1.0
tf-sentencepiece==0.1.82
torch==1.3.1
tqdm==4.40.1
typing==3.6.6
uritemplate==3.0.0
urllib3==1.25.7
werkzeug==0.16.0
wheel==0.33.6 ; python_version >= '3'
xlrd==1.2.0
xlwt==1.3.0
```

The above list is also generated in my Dockerfile:

```
# The first instruction is what image we want to base our container on
# We Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.7-stretch

# The enviroment variable ensures that the python output is set straight
# to the terminal with out buffering it first
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# create root directory for our project in the container
RUN mkdir /var/lib/django

# Set the working directory to /var/lib/django
WORKDIR /var/lib/django

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /var/lib/django
ADD . /var/lib/django/

# Install any needed packages specified in pipfile using piping
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pipenv

# Below are packages that need to be added to allow C tools
RUN apt update
RUN apt-get -y install libc-dev
RUN apt-get -y install build-essential

# Install requirements
RUN pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Run onDockerStartup file (executes python required functions for startup)
RUN python3 onDockerStartup.py

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000", "--noreload"]
```

However, when I start my application with `docker-compose` I get the following error:

```
django_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_1  |   File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
django_1  |     main()
django_1  |   File "manage.py", line 17, in main
django_1  |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
django_1  |     utility.execute()
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
django_1  |     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
django_1  |     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 60, in execute
django_1  |     super().execute(*args, **options)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
django_1  |     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 95, in handle
django_1  |     self.run(**options)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 104, in run
django_1  |     self.inner_run(None, **options)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
django_1  |     self.check(display_num_errors=True)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
django_1  |     include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
django_1  |     return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
django_1  |     new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
django_1  |     all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
django_1  |     url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
django_1  |     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 584, in url_patterns
django_1  |     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
django_1  |     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 577, in urlconf_module
django_1  |     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
django_1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
django_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
django_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
django_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
django_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
django_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
django_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
django_1  |   File "/var/lib/django/backend/urls.py", line 29, in <module>
django_1  |     path(r'search/', include('apps.search.urls')),
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
django_1  |     urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
django_1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
django_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
django_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
django_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
django_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
django_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
django_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
django_1  |   File "/var/lib/django/apps/search/urls.py", line 4, in <module>
django_1  |     from . import views
django_1  |   File "/var/lib/django/apps/search/views.py", line 24, in <module>
django_1  |     from .servicelayer.question_answer import find_answer_to_question
django_1  |   File "/var/lib/django/apps/search/servicelayer/question_answer.py", line 1, in <module>
django_1  |     from ml.use import embed_use
django_1  |   File "/var/lib/django/ml/use.py", line 9, in <module>
django_1  |     import tf_sentencepiece
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tf_sentencepiece/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
django_1  |     from tf_sentencepiece.sentencepiece_processor_ops import *
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tf_sentencepiece/sentencepiece_processor_ops.py", line 43, in <module>
django_1  |     _gen_sentencepiece_processor_op = tf.load_op_library(so_file)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py", line 61, in load_op_library
django_1  |     lib_handle = py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(library_filename)
django_1  | tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tf_sentencepiece/_sentencepiece_processor_ops.so.1.13.1: undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow12OpDefBuilder4AttrESs
```

How should I solve this error to get `sentencepiece` to start successfully?

Comment: be careful, in your Dockerfile, the `pipenv lock` command is run inside the container. So you are not replicating your outside environment in your docker. You should create the requirements.txt beforehand, and then build your docker image.

Comment: @GrégoireRoussel Good suggestion, I removed the line where I create the requirements.txt file in de Dockerfile. Then locally I 1) created a requirements.txt, 2) removed the virtual environment, 3) performed `pipenv install -r requirements.txt`, to confirm that the application would still work locally, it did! Then I recreated the Docker image and run the `docker-compose`, but unfortunately the same error occurs in the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was not in the setup of the Dockerfile, nor in the resulting packages in the requirements.txt. It was related to Tensorflow not being compatible with Python 3.7 (still strange that everything was working fine locally though). I moved to Python 3.6.5 on my local machine to test whether everything was working. Then I changed my Dockerfile to start with

```
FROM python:3.6-stretch
```

My application could now run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I have no skills in Django, but it seems that tensorflow is trying to find a package (with a strange name) and failing.

I'd first suggest to try and fix your docker container setup, and check that `pipenv lock -r` yield the same result inside and outside your container.

1) as you said in the commentaries, on the host pc

```sh
# Install requirements
RUN pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt
```

2) Replicate this env in the Docker container

```
# Dockerfile
#...

# Install requirements
ADD requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

3) to check:

```sh
docker container run -it --rm <your image> pipenv lock -r
```

That is as far as I can take you, I hope it'll be enough

Answer (score 0):

### Dockerfile

As stated in comments, first you `requirements.txt` file should be generated on the host machine, not in you Dockerfile.

```
# Install any needed packages specified in pipfile using piping
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pipenv

...

# Install requirements
RUN pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt
```

Will roughly generate a `requirements.txt` with only `pip` and `pipenv` inside.

So, generate your `requirements.txt` on your host and add it to your container:

```
# Install requirements
ADD requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

### SentencePiece

Then, your error seems related to a compiled library.
Python is looking for a symbol named `_ZN10tensorflow12OpDefBuilder4AttrESs` inside the `_sentencepiece_processor_ops.so.1.13.1` library, but it does not found it.
This generally happens when you have some version mismatch -- you are looking for a new symbol in a old version of library.

I don't know `sentencepiece` but I see that it exist two python packages: `sentencepiece` and `tf_sentencepiece`.
However, I see that `sentencepiece` is not listed in your `requirements.txt` (maybe you install it manually), and I feel that `tf_sentencepiece` requires it to work.

Moreover, I find it strange that you have `_sentencepiece_processor_ops.so.1.13.1` while `sentencepiece` last version is `0.1.85`.